# What is this grey LEGO light and sound element with neon green attachments?

Tags: part-identification

I consider my self to be somewhat of a LEGO collector, and have amassed quite a collection over the years. Recently, while looking through a few of my boxes I found this thing:

[image][image]

I got this years ago from a family that gave me all their remaining LEGO's when I was a child. It takes AA batteries and has 3 noises with accompanying lights when you press either of the three buttons. It has no part number that I've been able to find, and Googling "Lego green and grey lazer" is not very helpful. :P The only from of identification is the printing "LEGO group 1998" on the inside of the battery cover. I just thought I would ask if anyone knows what this is and what set this is from?

Answer (score 10):

That looks like the ["Electric, Light & Sound 4 x 20 x 5 Insectoid Stinger, Top"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=66088#T=C&C=10). The part number is **x239top** on bricklink.  It was only in 4 sets in *1998*.  The whole [Insectoids product line](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=34.305) was terminated less than a year later.

[image: the part]

Comment: Huh, I’m pretty sure I own two of those in a bin somewhere. I rather liked them as a kid; at the time I had no idea they were unpopular and it didn’t even register that the product line got discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

It is a "Electric, Light & Sound 4 x 20 x 5 Insectoid Stinger, Top" from the Insectoid line.
 I always wanted one of those sets.